# Leaflet: is there a method like panTo or setView that does not center when zooming out or in

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i have a zoomend function and inside it, is an if else for zoom value and i used panTo or setView to zoom with the latlng. but i dont want to center it when zooming out?

```
findMapNo(no).map.on("zoomend", function (e) {
            zoom = this.getZoom();
            console.log("zoomValue:",zoom);
            var diff = Oldzoom - zoom; 

            if(diff > 0 || diff < 0){ 
                //console.log('zoomed out');
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersLayer);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersCluster);
                findMapNo(no).map.closePopup(popup);

                diff = 0;
            } else if(diff == 0){
                //console.log('no change');
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer);
                findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
                findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
            }
            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to:

```
findMapNo(no).on("zoomend", function (e) {
            zoom = this.getZoom();
            console.log("zoomValue:",zoom);
            var diff = Oldzoom - zoom; 

            if(diff > 0 || diff < 0){ 
                if(diff > 0){
                    console.log('zoomed out');
                }else{                   
                    console.log('zoomed in');
                    findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
                 }
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersLayer);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersCluster);
                findMapNo(no).map.closePopup(popup);
            } else if(diff == 0){
                console.log('no change');
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer);
                findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
                findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
            }
            // I don't know if you do this elsewhere
            Oldzoom = zoom;
        });
```

And when you don't want do center the map, don't use panTo or setView. And why you want to set latlng when you don't want to center the map?

Comment: i dont want to center the map when zooming in and out. i just want to center the map when zoom == 20 and diff == 0. thats why im looking for other methods/codes other than panTo and setView

Answer (score 0):

> i dont want to center the map when zooming in and out. i just want to
>   center the map when zoom == 20 and diff == 0.

```
findMapNo(no).map.on("zoomend", function (e) {
        zoom = this.getZoom();
        console.log("zoomValue:",zoom);
        var diff = Oldzoom - zoom; 

        if(diff > 0 || diff < 0){ 
            //console.log('zoomed out');
            findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersLayer);
            findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersCluster);
            findMapNo(no).map.closePopup(popup);

            diff = 0;
        } else if(diff == 0){
            //console.log('no change');
            findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
            findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer);
            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
            findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
        }
        if(zoom == 20){
            findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about when i zoom where there is no marker? i will have zoom == 20 and diff == 0 there, but it will panTo to the last latlng...

Comment: add markers to a layer group, and if layer group is empty dont pan https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layergroup-getlayers